# Compiling VIM with breakindent patch

Tags: vim, compilation, ubuntu-12.04

In Ubuntu 12.04 Precise the only way to get breakindent patch working in VIM seems to be compiling VIM itself after patching it. Here's what I've done:

Install pbuilder and create local environment

```
sudo apt-get install pbuilder debootstrap
sudo pbuilder create --debootstrapopts --variant=buildd
```

Get the sources

```
sudo apt-get source vim
```

Patch them with breakindent patch retrieved from the [official repo](https://retracile.net/raw-attachment/blog/2011/08/23/21.30/vim-7.3.285-breakindent.patch)

```
cd vim-7.3.429
patch -p1 < vim-breakindent.patch
sudo pbuilder build vim_7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1.dsc
```

Pbuilder correctly generates deb packages but, after installing them, no breakindent option is available:

```
:set bri
E518: Unknown option: bri
```

Where's the mistake?
Thank you

Comment: Or you could just use the PPA: https://launchpad.net/~eudoxos/+archive/vim-breakindent

Comment: See the comments on the latest answer by Eudoxos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pbuilder` is still using the unmodified `.dsc`, `.orig.tar.gz`, and `.debian.tar.gz` to build the package.  Applying the patch to your local copy doesn't help.

You should probably add the patch to `debian/patches/` and `debian/patches/series`, bump the local version number in `debian/changelog` (`debchange` can help), and re-make the source archive (something like `dpkg-buildpackage -S`).

Comment: It worked! I'll give some instructions in the following answer

Answer (score 1):

Update: it worked following some more steps.

1. After `apt-get source`:

   ```
   cd vim-7.3.429
   sudo chmod u=rw,g=r,o=r ../vim-breakindent.patch
   sudo cp ../vim-breakindent.patch debian/patches/debian/.
   ```
2. added one new entry in `debian/changelog`, bumping version from `vim_7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1` to `vim_7.3.429-2ubuntu2.2`
3. added `debian/vim-breakindent.patch` at the end of `debian/patches/series`
4. generate new source package:

   ```
   sudo pdebuild
   ```
5. compile the new `.dsc`:

   ```
   sudo pbuilder build vim_7.3.429-2ubuntu2.2.dsc
   ```
6. install new debs:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/pbuilder/result/*.deb
   ```

Comment: Did the patch apply cleanly actually? I wrote the breakindent patch (and did not really maintain it for some time) and might use the retractile's version for the PPA. Thanks.

Comment: The patch applies correctly on the above mentioned VIM versions on Ubuntu, using retractile's patch file.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried and put new packages to my ppa at https://launchpad.net/~eudoxos/+archive/vim-breakindent . Thanks!