# Patch Vim with the breakindent patch on OS X with Homebrew

Tags: macos, vim, patch, homebrew

I'm on OS X 10.7 with Vim 7.3.

I'd like to install [the breakindent patch](https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent).

Here's a way to do it on Linux with `apt-get`:
[Compiling VIM with breakindent patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998516/compiling-vim-with-breakindent-patch).

How do I do this? I suppose it will involve building Vim via Homebrew (which is OK with me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use Mercurial to get the latest Vim source code:

   ```
   $ hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
   $ cd vim
   ```
2. Grab the patch.
3. Apply the patch as indicated in the linked thread:

   ```
   $ patch -p1 < /path/to/breakindent.patch
   ```
4. Configure Vim with the options you need (python/ruby support, custom location, etc.):

   ```
   $ ./configure --with-features=huge <other options>
   ```
5. Build and install:

   ```
   $ sudo make && make install
   ```

Comment: I guess I should have asked before I did this... did I just overwrite the Mac's standard vim? Nevertheless, either the patch didn't take, it's not a quality patch, or my system is still pointing to the original vim: $which vim => /usr/bin/vim

Comment: also, how to do with homebrew?

Comment: With the default configuration (if you don't specify a particular location at `./configure` time), Vim is installed at `/usr/local/bin/vim`. To use your new Vim, you simply need an alias in your `~/.bashrc` or wherever you put your aliases: `alias vim='/usr/local/bin/vim'`. I have no idea how to do that with homebrew : I've never felt the need to switch from MacPorts.

Comment: although, now such goodies as ":set syntax=on" don't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

I just modified the Homebrew formula for MacVim to optionally add that patch. If you want to try it out, you can download the formula at https://gist.github.com/4108848 and plunk it in /usr/local/Library/Formula; then install using `brew install --with-breakindent-patch macvim`.

(EDIT: I used to have a link to my GitHub fork of Homebrew here, but I've decided to delete that fork unless I actually submit anything to Homebrew. The old formula could optionally add a patch that's been added to the main Vim since then.)

Comment: I should warn you that brew might complain about macvim.rb being modified if you try to `brew update` and they've made changes to it upstream. I'm thinking about a pull request so they can integrate it into the master branch, but I'm not sure yet if they want formulas integrating arbitrary patches.

Comment: Another note: this installs MacVim -- Vim with a Cocoa GUI. romainl's solution just installs the text-mode Vim (and possibly the X11 front end).

Comment: Hmm... it's 2015, MacVim still doesn't have breakindent incorporated. @echristopherson, thank you for redoing the macvim.rb file, it's the only way I'm able to get this functionality into macvim. However it doesn't seem to work with the latest homebrew. Any chance you could issue a fix please?    `==> make getenvy
==> make
        ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [objects/os_unix.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [first] Error 2`

Comment: nvm. I compiled macvim with homebrew bleeding edge `brew install macvim --with-features=huge --override-system-vim --HEAD`

Answer (score 4):

As of June 25th 2014, VIM includes the breakindent patch by default – finally :-)

For more info, see https://retracile.net/blog/2014/07/18/18.00

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing from Homebrew, use:

`brew install macvim --with-features=huge --override-system-vim --HEAD`